# Input an empty string in my palindrome function

Tags: java, palindrome

It won't output a false statement. Not sure why it won't output the correct answer.

When testing, make sure your algorithm works in the following cases:

When given a word that is a palindrome, the algorithm returns "true"
When given a word that is not a palindrome, the algorithm returns "false"
When given a word that is an empty String, the algorithm does not crash.

```
 public class Palindrome {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         String input = "";// Set to test value
         char[] phrase = input.toCharArray();
         System.out.println(isPalindrome(phrase));
    }

 public static boolean isPalindrome(char[] input) {
    if (input == null)
        return false;

    int length = input.length;
    int c = 0;


    while(c <= length/2) {
        if(input[c] != input[length - 1 - c])
            return false;
        c++;
        }
    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `toCharArray()` will never return null so your `if (input == null)` condition will never trigger with the way you are passing the argument. an empty string returns an empty char array, so add a condition to test if the length is 0.

Comment: It does crash with an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for an empty string so I don't really understand your question. In main surround the code with `try {...} catch (Exception e) {                    
           e.printStackTrace();
        }`

Comment: @ChrisRollins I agree on testing for length is 0 but not that testing for null is incorrect, a method can't and shouldn't assume anything on how it is being called.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i never suggested removing the existing test for null. in fact I  used the word "add" intentionally rather than a word like "replace"

Answer (score 5):

You can do it the easy way:

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(isPalindrome("redivider"));
    System.out.println(isPalindrome("normal"));
  }

  public static boolean isPalindrome(String check) {
    return new StringBuilder(check).reverse().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(check);
  }
```

or just add "|| input.length == 0"

```
  public static boolean isPalindrome(char[] input) {
    if (input == null || input.length == 0) return false;

    int length = input.length;
    int c = 0;

    while (c <= length / 2) {
      if (input[c] != input[length - 1 - c]) return false;
      c++;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: @OliviaPulick, for your comment I see this solved the problem... so, you should mark this answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), it helps the community.